# Why is my @AfterClass method called multiple times?

Tags: java, maven, junit4, surefire

For testing REST services I have built a base class 'RestTestBase' that fires up an embedded Jetty server:

```
class RestTestBase {
    protected static AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootCtx;
    protected static AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx;
    private static Server jettyServer;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initSpringAndJetty() {
      if(jettyServer == null) {
        // init jetty and spring
      }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdownJetty() {
      if(jettyServer!=null && jettyServer.isRunning()) {
        // shutdown jetty and stop spring contexts
      }
    }
}
```

When I run this in a single-threaded environment from the Eclipse IDE, all is fine. Jetty and Spring are initialized only once, then all my tests run, then jetty is shut down.

However, when I run it in a multithreaded environment with Maven Surefire, the Jetty server is reinitialized for every single test. Why is that?

This is my surefire configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Probably because every instance is started in their own separate JVM.

Comment: I don't have much maven/surefire know-how, but it might be helpful to know that for every single test case JUnit actually creates an own object of the test class. If this objects are distributed Junit maybe calls the @*Class methods for every testcase-object

Comment: The method is called for each concrete class extending this base class.

Comment: @GermannArlington I don't use fork mode. For clarity I added my surefire configuration to the post

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, but only in surefire. Not in Eclipse. That's what puzzles me...

Comment: @BastianVoigt As far as I am aware what I describe is the default JUnit behavior (initialization per **test class**).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You mean this could be a bug in Eclipse's JUnit plugin?

Comment: That would be my first guess, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seems like this questions kind of misses the point, since the behaviour of @BeforeClass and @AfterClass is as expected.

I added a follow-up question to solve my real problem:

[How can I initialize a Spring applicationContext just once for all tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939226/how-can-i-initialize-a-spring-applicationcontext-just-once-for-all-tests)